# Scrollbar position after refreshing div

Tags: html, position, scrollbar, refresh

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function(){
$("#main").load("select.php?id='.$_GET['id'].'  #main")'
}, 3000)
</script>
```

I want to get the position of the scroll bar that I have in a div and load it in that position on refresh.

My div code is the following. It's in echo because it's in php file.

```
    echo "<div class='menu-page-menu-container'; style='height: 420px; overflow: auto'>";

                         echo "<br>";
                         echo "<br>";

                        echo "<table>";
                            echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td><img src='images/time.jpg'> Cet Time</td>";
                                echo "<td><img src='images/minute.jpg'> Min</td>";
                                echo "<td>Event</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            $minute=floor($row['timer']/60);
                            $seconds=$row['timer']-$minute*60;
                            if ($minute<10) 
                                $m='0'.$minute;
                            else $m=$minute;
                            if ($seconds<10) 
                                $s='0'.$seconds;
                            else $s=$seconds;
                            $min=$m.':'.$s;
                            $t=$row['cgtime'];

                            if(($row['keyword']=='SAFE HOME') || ($row['keyword']=='SAFE AWAY')){
                                echo "<tr bgcolor='#00FF00'>";
                                echo "<td><b>".$row['cgtime']."</b></td>";
                                echo "<td><b>".$min."'</b></td>";
                                echo "<td><b>".$row['keyword']."</b></td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                            }else if(($row['keyword']=='ATTACK HOME') || ($row['keyword']=='ATTACK AWAY')){
                                echo "<tr bgcolor='#0000FF'>";
                                echo "<td><b>".$row['cgtime']."</b></td>";
                                echo "<td><b>".$min."'</b></td>";
                                echo "<td><b>".$row['keyword']."</b></td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                            }else if(($row['keyword']=='DANGER HOME') || ($row['keyword']=='DANGER AWAY')|| ($row['keyword']=='DANGER FREE KICK HOME') || ($row['keyword']=='DANGER FREE KICK AWAY') || ($row['keyword']=='DANGER THROW-IN HOME') || ($row['keyword']=='DANGER THROW-IN AWAY')){
                                echo "<tr bgcolor='#FF0000'>";
                                echo "<td><b>".$row['cgtime']."</b></td>";
                                echo "<td><b>".$min."'</b></td>";
                                echo "<td><b>".$row['keyword']."</b></td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                            }else if(($row['keyword']=='YELLOW CARD HOME')|| ($row['keyword']=='YELLOW CARD AWAY')){
                                echo "<tr bgcolor='#FFFF00'>";
                                echo "<td><b>".$row['cgtime']."</b></td>";
                                echo "<td><b>".$min."'</b></td>";
                                echo "<td><b>".$row['keyword']."</b></td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                            }else if(($row['keyword']=='RED CARD HOME')|| ($row['keyword']=='RED CARD AWAY')){
                                echo "<tr bgcolor='#E80000 '>";
                                echo "<td><b>".$row['cgtime']."</b></td>";
                                echo "<td><b>".$min."'</b></td>";
                                echo "<td><b>".$row['keyword']."</b></td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                            }else if(($row['keyword']=='GOAL CONFIRMED')|| ($row['keyword']=='GOAL HOME') || ($row['keyword']=='GOAL AWAY') || ($row['keyword']=='MATCH STARTED') || ($row['keyword']=='MATCH STARTED') || ($row['keyword']=='END MATCH')){
                                echo "<tr class='invalid'>";
                                echo "<td><b>".$row['cgtime']."</b></td>";
                                echo "<td><b>".$min."'</b></td>";
                                echo "<td><b>".$row['keyword']."</b></td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                            }else{
                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td><b>".$row['cgtime']."</b></td>";
                                echo "<td><b>".$min."'</b></td>";
                                echo "<td><b>".$row['keyword']."</b></td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                            }

                        }
                        echo "</table>";
                        echo "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

i couldn't understand your question exactly but maybe this will give you an idea.

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$("#masthead").offset().top},'slow');

<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function(){
$("#main").load("select.php?id='.$_GET['id'].'  #main");   
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$("#main").offset().top},'slow'); 
}, 3000)
</script>
```

Comment: I have a div that reloads every 3 seconds. Each time that the div reloads, I want the scrollbar to have it's previous position before the div reloaded.